# http post does not work codeigniter,angular app

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter, post

I am making codeigniter app with angular on client side.So my post is not working someone please help.

Angular

```
$scope.posaljiKontroleru = function () {
                $scope.prosek = {kalorije: 0.0, proteini: 0.0, uh: 0.0, masti: 0.0};
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi',
                    data: JSON.stringify($scope.prosek),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

                }).success(function(data) {

                });
            }
```

CI controler

```
public function dodajBazi(){
        echo $this->input->post('kalorije');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can to solve it in differents ways.

First you can specify, in sending headers, form-urlencoded as content type

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

And use URLSearchParams object to add request params:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
for (let dataKey in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(dataKey)) {
    params.append(dataKey, data[dataKey]);
  }
}
```

For example:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('kalorije', 0.0);
params.append('proteini', 0.0);
params.append('uh', 0.0);
params.append('masti', 0.0);

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi',
  data: params,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(data) {
```

Otherwise if you want to send params as `application/json` you have to put input into `$_POST` var in controller:

`$_POST = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: I did the first method and i didnt echo anything

Comment: Can you try to send 0.0 as string? I change it in response

Answer (score 1):

```
$http({
    url: "http://example.appspot.com/rest/app",
    method: "POST",
    data:  {"kalorije": 0.0, "proteini": 0.0, "uh": 0.0, "masti": 0.0}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
})
```

Comment: When posting an answer, try to provide an explanation in addition to the code.